# How does auto-discovery work in JAXRS (Jersey 2)?

Tags: java, rest, jersey, jax-rs, jersey-2.0

I've been spending some time now on figuring out how exactly auto discovery works in Jersey 2 but I got more confused. Reading [Jersey documentation](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/deployment.html#deployment.autodiscoverable):

1. Features can be auto-discovered if they implement certain classes from Jersey SPI - (You can disable that with `CommonProperties.FEATURE_AUTO_DISCOVERY_DISABLE`)
2. Providers can be auto-discovered using *META-INF/services* facility (Can be disabled with `CommonProperties.METAINF_SERVICES_LOOKUP_DISABLE`)
3. Also disabling service lookup will disable Feature discovery too

Now I was wondering what would happen if a provider that's in *META-INF/services* is also registered using an auto-discovered feature.
Also if providers are registered automatically using above said mechanisms then what's the use of `@Provider`. Because I was under impression that `@Provider` is helping Jersey to discover my MBWs and MBRs automatically and I think it does.
I think documentation is not clear on this topic.
Any help to clarify this is highly appreciated.